# Suppose $P$ has $\hat{0}$ and $Int(P) \cong Int(Q)$. Show $\exists A, B$ so that $P \cong A \times B^*$ and $Q\cong A \times B$

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

This is Chapter 3, Problem 10b from Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics.

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be posets. If $P$ has a $\hat{0}$ and $Int(P) \cong Int(Q)$, show $\exists$ posets $ A, B$ so that $P \cong A \times B^*$ and $Q\cong A \times B$.

Following Stanley's hint, I let $f$ be an isomorphism $Int(P)\to Int(Q)$, and let $s ∈ Q$ be such that $f[0, 0]=[s, s]$. Then I defined $A = \{q \in Q: q \ge s\}$, $B=\{q \in Q: q \le s\}$. I was able to show that $P \cong A \times B^*$ via the following map:

> Suppose $f[0, a]=[b_a, c_a] \in Int(Q).$ Then we define $\phi(a)=(c_a,
>  b_a) \in A \times B^*$.

However, I'm unsure how to show that $Q \cong A \times B$. I attempted to define a map $\eta: A \times B \to Q$ via:

> Let $a \in A, b \in B.$ Then $b \le s \le a$. Suppose $f^{-1}[b,a]=[0, h].$ Then $\eta(a, b):= f[h, h]$.

I'm struggling to show that $\eta$ is an order-preserving map between posets, and I'm starting to question whether $\eta$ is the right map to use. How can I find an isomorphism $A \times B \to Q$?

Comment: 0 is the bottom element?  What is Int?   What does * mean?

Comment: 0 is the minimum element. Int(P) is the interval poset, ordered by inclusion. $P^*$ refers to the dual poset.

Comment: Are the intervals open, closed or both?   What's the dual?

Comment: Intervals are closed. The dual poset is the poset with the same elements but opposite order relations. (I.e. s≤ t in P iff t ≤ s in P^*)

Comment: Are P and Q finite?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: The finite case is trivial.  If P is finite, then int P, int Q and Q are finite.   As int P order isomorphic int Q, they are equinumerous.   Thus P and Q are equinumerous, hence  order isomorphic.   In general, isn't int P order isomorphic int Q equivalent to P order isomorphic Q?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Actually, no! int P order isomorphic to int Q is not equivalent to P order isomorphic Q. And I'm not sure that the finite-case argument is that trivial.

Comment: The condition that $P$ has a $0$ (though Q does not necessarily have a 0) is actually crucial here. In Stanley's book, part $(c)$ of this exercise shows that there are finite posets $P$, $Q$ (without $0$'s) with isomorphic interval posets such that the conclusion of $10(b)$ fails.

Comment: This is the counterexample provided in his book:  https://imgur.com/BhrjEnN

Comment: The example is missing.  int P = int reverse P.  Does int P = int Q imply P = reverse Q?

Comment: What do you mean by int P= int reverse P?

Comment: Maybe this is the confusion? We want to show $P\cong A \times (B^*)$, $Q \cong A \times B$.

Comment: (Note, we don’t assume local finiteness either)

Comment: int P = int P$^*$

Comment: Why is that a necessary point?

Comment: Isn’t it always true that int P is isomorphic to int P^*? Just map [s,t] to [t,s]